# Setting initial state values when using react-select with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-select

I am trying to use react-select (with multi-values) with Formik but unsure how to reflect values selected within my Formiks initialStates values.

I have the following:

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const myOptions= [
  { value: 'Food', label: 'Food' },
  { value: 'Being Fabulous', label: 'Being Fabulous' },
  { value: 'Unicorns', label: 'Unicorns' },
  { value: 'Kittens', label: 'Kittens' },
];


"props": {
    "myGroups": [
        {
            "myGroupName": "",
            "selectedOptions": []
        }
     ]
 }


<Select
   options={myOptions}
   isMulti={true}
   name={`myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`}
/>
```

I am able to populate the react-select list correctly but unsure what I need to do with setting: `myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions` to hold the values like:

```
"selectedOptions": [
                    "Food",
                    "Kittens"
                   ]
```

I'm assuming I will need an `onChange` function call and with Formik, will also need to use `setFieldValue`

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously worked on this library and required to do the exact same thing as you do.

Just add an `onChange` event. Then, have a variable `e` that will match with `handleChange` event from `Formik`.

```
<Formik initialValues={initialFormValues} validationSchema={formSchema} onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} enableReinitialize>
    {({ handleSubmit, handleChange }) => (
        <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
            <Select
                options={myOptions}
                isMulti={true}
                name={`myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`}
                onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                    let e = { target: { name: `myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`, value: selectedOption } };
                    handleChange(e);
                }}
            />
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine but results are coming back as `"selectedOptions": [
                    {
                        "value": "G2",
                        "label": "G2"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "G3",
                        "label": "G3"
                    }
                ]` - is it possible to have the returned result as `"selectedOptions": [
                        "G2",
                        "G3"
                ]` instead, i.e. just an array of selected values only?

Comment: I don't think it is possible as react-select required these two keys ```value``` and ```label``` in order to render properly. If you need to have array of items only, I would suggest to have another array and use ```setFieldValue()``` together with ```handleChange()```.

Comment: Just wondering if you can assist with my other SO thread that is similar?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67396379/setting-react-select-default-value-to-formik-initial-state-value

Comment: Using your code, I am unable to maintain formik state values. Are you able to please assist with this SO question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467795/unable-to-maintain-formik-state-values-within-react-select-component