# Setting react-select default value to Formik initial state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-select

I am using Formik with react-select and based on a value entered by the user at the beginning of the form, I would like to use this value as the default value within my react-select drop-down.

This is what I have with regards to Formik initial state values:

```
"props": {
    "myName": "",
    "myGroups": [
        {
            "myGroupName": "G1",
        },
        {
            "myGroupName": "G2",
        }
    ]
 }
```

Now within my react-select component, I would like to use `props.myGroups[0].myGroupName` (i.e. G1 from Formik values) and assign this value to my react-select, i.e.:

```
                <Select
                    id="color"
                    options={myOptions}
                    defaultValue={props.myGroups[0].myGroupName}
                    isMulti={true}
                    placeholder="-- Select a group --"
                />
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to achieve this. Unsure if I need to use `value=` instead as well as keep to `[{value: props.myGroups[0].myGroupName, label: props.myGroups[0].myGroupName }]` syntax?

Can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You need to have ```value``` so that ```react-select``` know where to made changes to and save it.

Comment: @GanHongJian - not too sure what you mean sorry - can you pls provide some context?

Comment: @GanHongJian -  Actaully I tried `value={myOptions.filter(option => option.value === props.myGroups[0].myGroupName)}` and it didn't work as I am not able to delete it or add any new ones

Comment: Any ideas pls @GanHongJian ?