# Unable to maintain formik state values within react-select component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state, formik, react-select

I am using react-select (multi-values) with Formik together with Material-UI Stepper (wizard) and have the values stored successfully within Formik's initialStates values but when I advance to the next screen, using conditional component rendering within my Stepper and then return back one screen where my react-select component resides, it no longer holds/shows the values that have already been selected within my react-select component even though the values are still in Formik's initialStates values.

My state is as follows which is storing my `selectedOptions` correctly:

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const myOptions= [
  { value: 'Food', label: 'Food' },
  { value: 'Being Fabulous', label: 'Being Fabulous' },
  { value: 'Unicorns', label: 'Unicorns' },
  { value: 'Kittens', label: 'Kittens' },
];


"props": {
    "myGroups": [
        {
            "myGroupName": "",
            "selectedOptions": [
                {
                    "value": "Unicorns",
                    "label": "Unicorns"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Kittens",
                    "label": "Kittens"
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
 }
```

Here is the code for the react-select component:

```
<Formik initialValues={initialFormValues} validationSchema={formSchema} onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} enableReinitialize>
    {({ handleSubmit, handleChange }) => (
        <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
            <Select
                options={myOptions}
                isMulti={true}
                name={`myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`}
                onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                    let e = { target: { name: `myGroups.${index}.selectedOptions`, value: selectedOption } };
                    handleChange(e);
                }}
            />
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

When returning, I expected to see both "Unicorns" and "Kittens" within the select but it's empty.

Any ideas how I can maintain state within this component? Can I perhaps somehow use `defaultValue' ?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to install this library : [formik-material-ui](https://stackworx.github.io/formik-material-ui/docs/api/material-ui#select)

You can after easy import:

`import { Select } from 'formik-material-ui';`

And use it in the Field component props.

Comment: Hi, but how will this help with my question? Can you please provide more info with regards to react-select.

Comment: Before ask this question please click on the link and try something.